# What are the differences between a presentation in academia and a presentation in industry?

Tags: presentation, industry

I think that I am pretty good at presenting my work during my PhD, and I am still being invited to conferences for some papers I did 2 years ago.

Now, I am working in industry. My manager always complains about my presentations and my reports.

I tried my best to follow his guidelines, but still he does not understand my presentations.

What might be the expectations in industry different than academia in terms of presenting some work?

Comment: It would seem that you are failing to present your work effectively... Major rethinking is probably necessary. Beyond that, it seems that no one on this site could really answer your question in any precise way.

Comment: ... that is, your remark that you are "excellent at presenting work I did in my PhD" has to be taken in a very qualified way: for _certain_audiences_, perhaps this is so. Apparently not for all. Also, statistically, many novices' notion of "excellent presentation" is fairly unrelated to more-expert, more-jaded, more-sophisticated notions of that. Different people desire different things at different times in their trajectories.

Comment: There are two problems with this question. One, you seem to ask the wrong people. Workplace SE seems to  be a better site because your problem is industry workplace related. Two, _My manager always complains about my presentations and my reports._. You need to clarify what are his major complaints. Without knowing the complaints, how do you expect people to help you to address them?

Comment: You need to tell your managers what they want to know, rather than what you want to tell them.

Comment: From your pseudo I'll take that you are a physicist. Is your manager a physicist too ? Because, as paul garrett pointed out, the audience type is important. Do you present to other colleague or just your manager ? In the former case, do your colleagues share your manager opinion ? Additionally, being invited to a conference is more likely linked to your research quality than your presentation skill. I have seen terrible presentation from highly ranked scientists...

Comment: @paulgarrett I'd be happy to answer this question if it weren't on hold. I do think this is the right forum for it.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning As is, I think it would be probably a better fit for [Workplace SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I did vote to reopen... but/and I'd hope that the questioner can add some helpful details.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Workplace SE might send the OP here because the question asks how to transition from academic experience. Arguably more people here than there would be interested.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I asked there in chat, but probably you're right that there is more people here that would be interested.I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 7):

The comments above are correct--you're probably pitching to the wrong audience, and your presentation skills are probably not as good as you think they are. To put it undiplomatically, the great majority of (STEM) presentations in academia are horrible, but after a half-decade or so of grad school you become inured to this and recalibrate your expectations. You've probably noticed that a genuinely engaging and accessible academic presentation is often judged to be less deep and interesting than an incomprehensible one. This is not going to be the case in a business environment.

The key difference is that the focus in a business presentation is on utility: You're not just trying to convey information, you're trying to be useful to your team and to the company. What are the people in your audience going to do with the content of your presentation when it's over? They want usable information, and they want it quickly and efficiently. Here are some ways to do this:

- Include a "30,000-foot view" and (metaphorically) keep it in sight throughout the presentation.
- Keep the narrative of your information focused. That is, make sure it's clear why each piece of information is relevant to whatever point you're trying to make.
- Leave detailed background explanations to follow-up questions.
- Be parsimonious and efficient in your flow of information. Pictures are generally better than words.

I'm assuming you're in a role where you process and produce data, so that your reports and presentations are informative rather than persuasive. But many of the same principles would apply if you are trying to convince your audience of something.

A final remark: People who give business presentations practice them. You probably have access to tech for recording a video of yourself, or at least a screencast with audio of your presentation. Use it.

Comment: "great majority of (STEM) presentations in academia are horrible" this is so TRUE, I wonder if there is any research about this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what is your employer feedback to the presentation but in general, one thing that I noticed that in academia we tend to emphasize methodology for about 10 slides, and in the industry, they only have one slide of the method and 10 slides of results and implication of results aka. discussion.

If I were in your position, I would use the narrative language of a TED talk. Why this format? because this form is most suitable for the wide audience. I assume that your boss and people in your collective are from various background.

We need more info about your current job, what industry is and who are your co-workers professionally. But if you are people from different backgrounds, you need to find a common denominator for all of you, so your ppt can be clearly understandable to the wide audience.